# How do I extend a protected core function?

Tags: 8, plugins

In core\modules\menu_link_content\src\Plugin\Menu\MenuLinkContent.php is a `protected function getEntity()`.

I want to "make" this function public. Can I do this by extending the class `MenuLinkContent`? And if so, how do I extend this class (in a custom module)?

Here is what I already got (location: modules/my_module/src/Plugin/Menu/MenuLinkContentHelper.php):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkBase;

/**
 * Provides the menu link plugin for content menu links.
 */
class MenuLinkContentHelper extends MenuLinkContent {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function my_function() { // should override getEntity()

    // give me the return of getEntity() as $value

    return $value;
  }

}
```

But I don't know if that works or how I can make this accessible.

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a plain PHP question; Drupal doesn't change PHP syntax, so the answer for your question is not Drupal-specific. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377744/why-does-php-allow-protected-and-private-methods-to-be-made-public-via-an-overri.

Comment: Also _How do I call a protected method of a class in a public method of a class that extends that class?_ is a Drupal question. You do it with Drupal as you do it with plain PHP.

Comment: I think it could be a valid answer if you ask what you really need to do. You figured out the php syntax, but actually having your custom class used in favor of the default one is absolutely drupal specific. But there might be a better solution for it as well. I suggest you create a new question and ask about the problem that you actually need to solve and what you tried so far.